# HDFS replication factor

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I'm uploading a file to HDFS, if I set the replication factor to 1 then the file splits gonna reside on one single machine or the splits would be distributed to multiple machines across the network ?

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=1 -copyFromLocal file.txt /user/ablimit
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Hadoop : Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> Hadoop’s default strategy is to place the first replica on the same node as the client (for
>   clients running outside the cluster, a node is chosen at random, although the system
>   tries not to pick nodes that are too full or too busy). The second replica is placed on a
>   different rack from the first (off-rack), chosen at random. The third replica is placed on
>   the same rack as the second, but on a different node chosen at random. Further replicas
>   are placed on random nodes on the cluster, although the system tries to avoid placing
>   too many replicas on the same rack.

This logic makes sense as it decreases the network chatter between the different nodes. But, the book was published in 2009 and there had been a lot of changes in the Hadoop framework.

I think it depends on, whether the client is same as a Hadoop node or not. If the client is a Hadoop node then all the splits will be on the same node. This doesn't provide any better read/write throughput in-spite of having multiple nodes in the cluster. If the client is not same as the Hadoop node, then the node is chosen at random for each split, so the splits are spread across the nodes in a cluster. Now, this provides a better read/write throughput.

One advantage of writing to multiple nodes is that even if one of the node goes down, a couple of splits might be down, but at least some data can be recovered somehow from the remaining splits.

Comment: I think you last statement is not correct. If one of the  node is down and it has blocks of input data, there is no way for NameNode to recover the file or even hand out the remaining blocks (Assuming replication factor of 1)

Comment: Block location choosing strategy is documented differently in the hadoop docs , please check https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you set replication to be 1, then the file will be present only on the client node, that is the node from where you are uploading the file.

Comment: This is true _iff_ the client node also runs a DataNode service.

Comment: Is this true even if the client-local datanode is full?  i.e. will the copy fail as opposed to using a different DN?

Answer (score 0):

- If your cluster is single node then when you upload a file it will be spilled according to the blocksize and it remains in single machine.
- If your cluster is Multi node then when you upload a file it will be spilled according to the blocksize and it will be distributed to different datanode in your cluster via pipeline and NameNode will decide where the data should be moved in the cluster.

HDFS replication factor is used to make a copy of the data (i.e) if your replicator factor is 2 then all the data which you upload to HDFS will have a copy.

Comment: What if you change the replication factor value in hdfs-site.xml after a file has been uploaded to hdfs - will the system automatically replicate it or would you need to execute an hdfs balancer command?

Answer (score 0):

If you set replication factor is 1 it means that the single node cluster. It has only one client node http://commandstech.com/replication-factor-in-hadoop/. Where you can upload files then use in a single node or client node.